# Protocols with Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, protocols

I have a project where I have set up a protocol to pass information back from one TableViewController to a ViewController. Everything worked fine and as expected, but I decided to embed in a Navigation Controller to the TableViewController so I could add a "DONE" barButtonItem to dismiss the Controller when the user is done. Since embedding in the navigation controller, the button works well, the TablieViewController looks identical, but none of its features and methods that use the Protocol and Delegate work, and if I remove the NavigationController everything works. Could someone explain how I can fix this issue? I am fairly new to iOS and objective c.

Here is the prepareForSegue method in the NoteViewController

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[ToolTableViewController class]]) {
    ToolTableViewController *targetVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    targetVC.toolDelegate = self;
    targetVC.autoCorrectIsOn = self.autoCorrectIsOn;
    targetVC.undoAvailable = self.undoAvailable;
    targetVC.redoAvailable = self.redoAvailable;
}
```

}

ToolTableViewController.h

```
@protocol ToolTableViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>                              
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <ToolTableViewControllerDelegate> toolDelegate;
```

ToolTableViewController.m - example of a method called

```
-(void)clearInputText{
//    NSLog(@"Clear Method Selected");
[self.toolDelegate didClearInputText];
```

}

NoteViewController.m

```
-(void)didClearInputText{
self.noteTextView.text = @"";
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Comment: There's no reason embedding your controller in a navigation controller should cause your delegate protocol to stop working, unless it's affecting how you set the delegate. You need to show your code.

Comment: Where do you set the delegate object? You embed UIViewController subclasses into Navigation controllers, not the other way around. Can you show some code?

Comment: @joakim I have edited some code in. all this worked before I embedded in (in storymode) a NavigationController

Comment: Is the order of the controllers  NoteViewController --> navigationController -->ToolTableViewController?

Comment: Then the destination view controller should be the navigation controller, not ToolTableViewController. Is the if statement in prepareForSegue executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your table view controller is embedded in a navigation controller, it's the navigation controller that will be the destination view controller of the segue. Also, it would be better to use the identifier of the segue for the if statement, rather than the class of the destination view controller (I'm using "SegueToTable" as the identifier, change that to whatever you put for the identifier). Therefore, prepareForSegue should look like this,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueToTable"]) {
        UINavigationController *nav = segue.destinationViewController;
        ToolTableViewController *targetVC = nav.topViewController;
        targetVC.toolDelegate = self;
        targetVC.autoCorrectIsOn = self.autoCorrectIsOn;
        targetVC.undoAvailable = self.undoAvailable;
        targetVC.redoAvailable = self.redoAvailable;
    }
```

}

Comment: Magic, thank you so much! I finally learnt what was wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate methods are called just fine (based on the sample you pasted).

Since your controllers are embedded in a navigation controller now, you should use:
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]

Before, you were presenting your controllers modally, that's why dismissViewController worked fine then but not now ( in the context of a nav controller).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I tried changing dismissVIewController and replacing it with popViewControllerAnimated, but it did not work. The methods themselves don't get called when I press the tableViewCell, as I put an NSLog in the methods to test they are being called and it is not printed out. Anything else you can think of?

Comment: yes, when I press the Clear cell in the tableView, the method gets called with [self.toolDelegate didClearInputText] as shown above. I just put a NSLog() statement in the method to make sure it is called is well, and it does. All this worked before the NavigationController, and if I go back to before I embedded it in, everything still works. Thats why its so strange. Also, not sure if this helps, but if I hold down the control key in xCode and press the didClearInputText, I get two options pop up (as expected), One for the .h file, one for the NoteViewController didClearInputText

Comment: Try deleting the method from the header (.h) file first. If this does not work, try deleting the connection from the storyboard connections panel and re-wire the IBAction from scratch.

Comment: No luck. ill try to delete the ToolTable class and write the code again and see if that works. Is this meant to happen with NavigationControllers?

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside clearInputText. Is toolDelegate maybe nil?